# NSScrollView scroll downward when resizing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSScrollView with a custom view inside and when I resize the NSScrollView, the height grows and it scrolls upward.  Unless there is an easier way, I'll probably have to register a notification to see if the view changes size and then adjust the scrollPoint: to a new point.  I'm having trouble getting method to work smoothly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question comes up from time to time, because it's not obvious.

The content will pin to the top left if `[contentView isFlipped] == YES`.