# Content of NSScrollView sticks at bottom when resizing

Tags: swift, xcode, nsview, nsscrollview

When I add a custom `NSView` to my `NSScrollView` via `documentView` and resize the window the content sticks always to the bottom of the window (so the scroll view is always scrollt to the bottom when the window is resized).
Is there a way to keep the scroll view scrolled to the top when the window is resized?

[image: Original]

[image: Resized]

Edit: Uploaded reproducible example:
https://github.com/nathasmike/sample1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSScrollView scroll downward when resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384014/nsscrollview-scroll-downward-when-resizing)

Comment: Or [NSScrollView how to start from top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871945/nsscrollview-how-to-start-from-top-left-corner)

Comment: Unfortunately not. These solutions make sure that the content sticks at the top when the window is enlarged. It does not solve the problem that the content sticks at the bottom when the window is shrunk down smaller that the content.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I added a link to a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoresizing mask of the custom view is translated into constraints. To prevent this do

```
myCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myScrollView.documentView = myCustomView
```

Add constraints to the custom view and its subviews.

Another solution is removing the autoresizing mask from the custom view in the xib.